# Iterate over Playing Cards array and verify suits

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm working with an array that looks like this:

```
cards = [#<Cardshark::Card:0x9200cc @rank=:ace, @suit=:coins>, etc]
```

Each of 4 suits (coins, swords, cups, clubs) contains ranks ace through seven and 3 face cards for a total of 40 cards per "deck"

I am looking to write an rspec test to verify that the array contains 4 suits. I started going down the path of using `@cards.select` with a block using regular expressions and that got ugly pretty fast.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Enumerable#group_by:

```
num_suits = cards.group_by { |card| card.suit }.length
```

In IRB:

```
~$ irb
>> groups = (1..10).group_by { |n| n % 4 }
=> {0=>[4, 8], 1=>[1, 5, 9], 2=>[2, 6, 10], 3=>[3, 7]}
>> groups.length
=> 4
```

Comment: group_by is part of the Ruby API, it's not part of Rails. I'll edit my post to show you how to use it in irb.

Comment: Yes, I was messing it up in irb. I kept trying .first on the object instead of trying to get the first Card. It was as simple as italian.cards.group_by {|card| card.suit}.length == 4.

Comment: Note you can write this as num_suits = cards.group_by(&:suit).length

Comment: @steenslag not that it matters here in this tiny example but a using a Proc like that is going to be 2-3 times slower in 1.8.7 than in 1.9.2. They are almost identical however in 1.9.2

Comment: You can with most implementations, however it is less portable as Symbol#to_proc is not always available. If you're sure that the version of Ruby you're running in will support it then go for it, otherwise it is better to use the older, more verbose notation.

Comment: @steenslag http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/161089 there's what I could dig up on it. From what I've seen the two are very comparable in speed in 1.9.2 though.

Comment: I thought that the Symbol#to_proc form was actually faster in modern implementations.

Answer (score 2):

```
describe Cardshark, "@cards" do
  it "should contain four suits" do
    suits = @cards.map { |card| card.suit }.uniq
    suits.size.should be 4
  end
end
```